# Using dropdown list

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have created 2 models to contain my databases, namely the **ADMIN** to allow creation of the project names, project owners, form numbers etc and a **SUPERVISORLOGIN** to allow users to input details of the projects to be selected.

I have created a relationship between the 2 models and I want the `Admin users` to input the list of `projects` to be worked on and for the `supervisors` who will work on the projects to input details of their work on the specific locations/dates etc of the work they carried out.

I managed to create a drop down list to allow the supervisors to select the project, but only the project id numbers are shown. I want the project names to be shown instead. How do I create a drop down list to show my project names, not the id no?

Comment: which language? what have you got so far?

Comment: English. In my Admin I just input 2 project names, namely TOP and KOL. I am stuck at trying to get these names in the drop down list. So far I only got the ID numbers, 1 and 2 in the drop down list.